# Flash Builder 4 How to create a add button to add instance of textbox and combobox?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I have tried to work on a simple form with Flash Builder 4, but was stuck in creating the dynamic addition of the instance for a textbox and combobox within a Hbox.

I have created an HBox component with a textbox and a combo box. I then create a button Add new Row, to add a new row of Hbox on the runtime.

May I know how can I create the add to make it able to add new hbox component on clicking of the button, such that when i click the hbox 3 times, I should have 3 rows of the component instance and the button is still at the bottom of these components?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the code:

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[           
        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
            var textInput:TextInput = newTextInput();               
            vbox.addChildAt(textInput,0);
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:VBox id="vbox">
    <mx:Button click="button1_clickHandler(event)" label="Click"/>  
</mx:VBox>
```

I'm creating a simple text field, and not a custom component as in your case, however I think you can get the idea. I also recommend isolating your mxml component (hbox+childrens) in a different file, for better clarity.

Comment: thanks that gave me a start, i managed to add to a vbox, but how can i position the button to the bottom of newly added children?

Comment: it's hard to have a clear idea without more details - a picture describing the intended layout or the actual code (or both of them)